# mysql : create virtual column et set defaut value

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have this mysql query :

```
Select name from my_table
```

This query return me this result :

```
 NAME
-------
 name1
 name2
 name3
```

How can I create a virtual column and set a defaut value in this column ?
I want this result :

```
 NAME   | Virtual Column
------------------------  
 name1  |    defaut_value
 name2  |    defaut_value
 name3  |    defaut_value
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like this:

```
SELECT name, 'default_value' AS "A Virtual Column"
FROM my_table
```

This is legal this way, because in the `SELECT` clause you can select what so called, in the SQL standard, a *value expression*. Where value expression can be either of the following<sup>1</sup>:

[image]

---

<sup>1: <sup>This image from: [SQL Queries for Mere Mortals(R): A Hands-On Guide to Data Manipulation in SQL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201433362)</sup></sup>